# Android SeekBar Math

Tags: android, math

I have a seekbar, and would like to take the `progress` (0 - 100) and convert it to -100 to +100. I am not too good at coming up with formulas like this, so I was hoping I could get some thoughts on a formula to do this.

If setting default min and max values are possible I don't want to do that because the seekbar min and max values could change so doing math is better idea IMO.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rescale from a width of 100 to 200 first, then set your basis to -100. So your function would be something like f(x) = x*2 - 100

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `x - 100`? If the value was 200, then `x*2 - 100` would be `300`.

Comment: @kcoppock 0 maps to -100, 100 maps to +100. 200 is outside the domain (0-100).

Comment: But if the SeekBar width is 200 then the range would be 0-200, right? Which would then need to be mapped to (-100, 100)? I'm probably just misunderstanding you. :)

Comment: I'm just saying if he wants to map (0,100) to (-100,100) linearly then the formula I gave is the way to do it. You are correct inasmuch as if he wanted to map (0,200) to (-100,100) then f(x)=x-100 would be the answer to that question.